# Building a Maven Project with Class Files

Tags: java, maven

My Maven project uses a forked JAR of spring-security-oauth.

I'd like to add extra debugging statements, so I unzipped the spring-security-oauth-custom.jar.

But, when I navigated to the `org/springframework/security/oauth/common/signature` directory, I saw `class` files.

How can I use the `source` files instead since I can't modify the `class` files?

Comment: Why not just add extra breakpoints instead of extra debugging statements?

Comment: I can't attach to the binaries running on Tomcat because I don't have access to the Linux server. `long story...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artifacts in Maven are immutable. Assuming you let Maven grab `spring-security-oauth-custom.jar` from a Maven repository, you can't just edit the contents of the JAR file and expect things to work.

You'll have to do the following:

1. Download the source bundle for `spring-security-oauth-custom.jar`.
2. Expand the sources somewhere.
3. Make your modifications.
4. Create a new artifact out of this new module (including creating a new POM file for it, giving it unique Maven coordinations such as `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`).
5. Install the new artifact in your own artifact repository.
6. Adjust your calling module (that is, the module calling `spring-security-oauth-custom`) to depend on your modified version, instead of the original.

Comment: Thanks, @Isaac. I mistakenly thought that I had `java` source files for the other files. Sounds like I just need to get the Maven project from a colleague.

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom built JAR file like that you should deploy it in your local repository and use it as a regular dependency. You can either put it in your repository manually, or you can use the [`maven-install-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html). Either way, you should create a unique version number for it so it does not "collide" with any official Spring artifacts.